# Connecting mysql database to searxng

Tags: python, mysql, docker, linode, searxng

I have been running searxng using docker (Docker version 23.0.5, build bc4487a) on my rpi4 locally and I wanted to connect it to my MySQL server on Linode. However, whenever I enter my values in the settings.yml under the MySQL section and perform a search - it does not return any value from mysql
**
settings.yml**

```
name: mysql_connector
    engine: python
    module: /home/director/did_search/searxng/myscript.py
    user: 
    password: 
    host:
    database: connecter
    port: 3306
    limit: 10
    query_str: "SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE LastName=%(query)s"
    shortcut: mysql
```

**
Here is the myscript.py file**

```
`# SPDX-License-Identifier: AGPL-3.0-or-later
# lint: pylint
"""MySQL database (offline)

"""

# import error is ignored because the admin has to install mysql manually to use
# the engine
import mysql.connector  # pyright: ignore # pylint: disable=import-error

engine_type = 'offline'
auth_plugin = 'caching_sha2_password'
host = ""
port = 3306
database = "connecter"
username = ""
password = ""
query_str = "SELECT * from Persons WHERE LastName=%(query)s"
limit = 10
paging = True
result_template = 'key-value.html'
_connection = None


def init(engine_settings):
    global _connection  # pylint: disable=global-statement

    if 'query_str' not in engine_settings:
        raise ValueError('query_str cannot be empty')

    if not engine_settings['query_str'].lower().startswith('select '):
        raise ValueError('only SELECT query is supported')

    _connection = mysql.connector.connect(
        database=database,
        user=username,
        password=password,
        host=host,
        port=port,
        auth_plugin=auth_plugin,
    )


def search(query, params):
    query_params = {'query': query}
    query_to_run = query_str + ' LIMIT {0} OFFSET {1}'.format(limit, (params['pageno'] - 1) * limit)

    with _connection.cursor() as cur:
        cur.execute(query_to_run, query_params)

        return _fetch_results(cur)


def _fetch_results(cur):
    results = []
    for res in cur:
        result = dict(zip(cur.column_names, map(str, res)))
        result['template'] = result_template
        results.append(result)

    return results
`
```

I have tried connecting the database locally to see if there was a problem with my linode server but this did nothing either.

I installed the mysql-connector-python library on both the linode server and the raspberry pi to determine whether this would resolve the issues it did not.

I have set up a low privilege user on mysql called lowlevel and gave it only SELECT permissions for the databases I want to use. The lowlevel use can be accessed from anywhere therefore I do not think it is a problem of remote connection...but I could be wrong.

I appreciate any help I can receive